# How to get file date Accessed?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for this function from std::filesystem but can't figure it out.

How to access this information?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean [last_write_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time)?

Comment: I disagree with the close reason on this. The linked duplicate is specific to last write/modified time; however, the question also includes created and accessed times, which are not available via `std::filesystem`, and not part of the linked "duplicate".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments. I had a mistake. it is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only write time (Modified in your screenshot) is accessible via standard libraries. You'd need to use platform-specific APIs to get access to the other information.

For example, assuming Windows (based on the screen shot), you'd use [`GetFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime); this function is able to retrieve the created, modified, and accessed times. You will need a handle to the file. The link above includes a link to a full example, but summarizing the example essentially you can do:

```
HANDLE hFile = /* get the file handle */
FILETIME ftCreate, ftAccess, ftWrite;

GetFileTime(hFile, &ftCreate, &ftAccess, &ftWrite);
```

Comment: The same information can be retrieved *without* opening a handle to the file (and thus affecting its access time) by using [`FindFirstFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) or [`GetFileAttributesEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) instead of `GetFileTime()`